# CakePhp multiple table data fetch on single page

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakePHP try to create a blog site where user add blog after category select, I have one categories table : fields: category_id, name and posts table : fields : id, category_id , title, body. 
I want to fetch all categories to a dropdown list. When user add new post they have to select category first then he is able to post anything..

My PostsController:

```
<?php 


class PostsController extends AppController{



    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session','Paginator');

    public function index(){

        $this->Paginator->setting = array(
            'limit' =>'10',
            'order' => array('Post.id' =>'Desc')
            /*'conditions' => array(
                'Post.user_id' => AuthComponent::user(id)
                )*/
            ); 

        $arrPosts = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');

        $this->set('posts', $arrPosts);

    }

    public function view($id = null){

        if(!$id){

            throw new NotFoundException(__("Error Processing Request ID"));

        }
        $post =$this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$post){

            throw new NotFoundException(__("Error Processing Request POST"));

        }
        $this->set('post',$post);   
    }

    public function add(){

         // HERE I want to fetch all categoryies from categories table and want to send to view

        if($this->request->is('post')){

            $this->Post->create();
            if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Blog Posted Sucessfully'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to Post Blog '));
            }
        }


    }
}
?>
```

I want to show my category in add form:

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action you need to use `$this->set()` to set a View variable. As long as you've got your associations setup correctly in your Post model you should then be able to use:-

```
$this->set('categories', $this->Post->Category->find('list'));
```

Cake's FormHelper should automatically know that the `Post.category_id` form field wants to be a select input with `$categories` as the options.

One further point, it would be better to set the view variables after processing the form as you won't need them if it saves correctly and so can reduce the number of database queries by 1.

If you use `find('all')` to retrieve the categories you will need to convert it into the format used by `find('list')` which can easily be done using `Hash::combine()`:-

```
$categories = $this->Post->Category->find('all');
$this->set(
    'categories', 
    Hash::combine($categories, '{n}.Category.id', '{n}.Category.name')
);
```

The only real value in doing this is if you need `$categories` for something else.

Comment: But i want to print it using find('all');

** $this->set('categories', $this->Post->Category->find('all'));**

Comment: If you're using find('all') you won't get the data in the correct form for the form helper. I've updated my answer to show you how you can use find('all') and correct the format.

Comment: @RahulSaxena Wanting to do something _one_ way, and doing something the _right_ way, is often mutually exclusive, just like in this case, there's no reason to use an `all` find, from looking at your question it makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

public function add(){

```
  /*Here get the category list & set the view (ctp file)*/
 $this->set('categories', $this->Post->Category->find('list'));

    if($this->request->is('post')){

        $this->Post->create();
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Blog Posted Sucessfully'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to Post Blog '));
        }
    }

}
```

//Set The dropdown in ctp file 
$this->Form->input('category_id', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>'categories'));

Comment: i am using find('all') hence it return array like 


array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'Category' => array(
   'category_id' => '1',
   'name' => 'Php'
  )
 ),
 (int) 1 => array(
  'Category' => array(
   'category_id' => '3',
   'name' => 'Ajax'
  )
 )
}

how to print it?